DML operation Insert not allowed on Survey in the test class
I'm creating a test class for the Survey objects like: Survey, surveyResponse, surveyQuestion, and SurveyQuestionResponse.
getting an error:
DML operation Insert not allowed on Survey and for all the objects I mentioned above,
Survey s = new Survey();

insert s;

if I'm adding any field to store the data ex: s.name = 'test name'; then getting a new error: field is not writeable s.name
please help me,

As you can see from the Object Reference Doc for Survey, you can't use DML to create this object. Note that for deployment purposes, Surveys are Flows.

Supported Calls
describeLayout(), describeSObjects(), getDeleted(), getUpdated(), query(), retrieve(), search()

Hence mocking Survey via DML in a test method is not possible.
How to workaround?
Option 1 - annotate the test method with @SeeAllData=true
It pains me to even write this option but it would allow you to mock SurveyInvitation as a child of an org's Survey.
Option 2 Refactor your code-under-test to use the Selector pattern (Preferred)
This would allow you, at testmethod time, to mock Survey, SurveyInvitation, etc as SObjects rather than as DML'd objects.
How you inject your mock selectors into the code-under-test can be done in many ways. I personally use fflib ApexMocks pattern but there are others like Amoss. You can also use simple dependency injection into the classes that invoke the selector class methods. These are all built on top of Test.StubApi.
One way or another, you need to move the SOQL into a selector class that can be mocked and injected at testmethod time. The concept is the same as mocking the HttpCallout in test methods.

FYI - I have a trigger on SurveyQuestionResponse, is there a way to write a test class for that trigger? if yes, please explain it to me with an example.
One more thing, if salseforce allows us to write a trigger on that object so there would be something to do it

I gave you two options; one requires seeAllData=true; the other refactoring your code and using mock selectors
